# ¿Qué significa la expresión “de nana con la pelota”?

Tags: traducción

En [un artículo de El País (de España) sobre un partido de fútbol](http://deportes.elpais.com/deportes/2015/01/15/actualidad/1421341293_687131.html) se lee la frase (completa para dar más contexto): "El Madrid ya estaba fulminado y el Atlético, como ya casi es costumbre en los últimos años, en pantuflos en casa del vecino, con Torres entronizado en su vuelta al nido y Arda, su sustituto, ***de nana con la pelota***, tan despreciada por los suyos hasta entonces."

Según la RAE, nana significa:

1. Canto con que se arrulla a los niños
2. Especie de saco pequeño, a veces con capucha, con una abertura anterior que se cierra generalmente con cremallera y que sirve de abrigo para niños de pecho

Y varias cosas más en las Américas. Ninguna de las dos definiciones tiene sentido en este contexto (bueno, para mí).

Comment: Me parece que quiere decir, más bien, *acunando la pelota*; es decir, tratándola con mimo, a diferencia de lo que habían hecho hasta entonces según el artículo. Pero tampoco acabo de entenderlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es cierto que entre los significados de `nana` están los que has puesto en la pregunta, pero si miras la [definición de la RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=nana) verás que hay alguno más, entre ellos "abuela" o **"niñera"**. Están también *"ama"* con la acepción de

> mujer que cría una criatura ajena

e incluso "empleada del hogar".

Dado que las abuelas suelen ayudar mucho en el cuidado de los niños, e incluso puede estar entre las tareas de una empleada de hogar, esas cuatro acepciones tienen la connotación de "alguien que cuidada un niño".

No soy un especialista en fútbol, pero tras leer [el artículo](http://deportes.elpais.com/deportes/2015/01/15/actualidad/1421341293_687131.html) creo que el significado es que *los rojiblancos* parecían medio dormidos en el partido, la estrella principal (Torres) no estuvo a la altura de lo que se esperaba de él y el tal *Arda* fue el que tuvo que hacer el esfuerzo. Por eso dicen que estaba como de **"niñera del balón"**, posiblemente custodiándolo, paseándolo de arriba a abajo en el campo, recuperándolo cuando el equipo lo perdía, etc (pero sin llegara hacer nada útil con él).

Comment: Esta explicación me parece muy probable. Usar nana con tal sentido es poco común, verdad? Voy a esperar un poquito para aceptar tu contesta para ver si alguien tiene otra explicación. Gracias.

Comment: @JohnBarça, suponiendo que yo esté en lo cierto, si el escritor hubiese dicho "niñera" le habría entendido todo el mundo. Con "**nana** del balón", paradójicamente, hay que haber visto el partido para entender el significado de la frase (y del artículo). "Nana" tiene más el sentido que explica Gorpik en su comentario (canción de cuna) que el de cuidadora.

Comment: Si hubiera visto el partido no habría tenido que leer el resumen. :D